# Support for transformation of Standard Normal distribution PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I was studying probability distribution functions and had a particular question about an exercise problem. The problem goes:

> Let $Z$ ~ $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Find the PDF for $Z^4$.

I've solved the problem, but missed defining the support, and frankly am not sure how the support came to be. Allow me to elaborate.

**My Solution**

Let $Y = Z^4$. We cannot use the change of variables formula due to the fact that $y = z^4$ is not strictly increasing or decreasing. We will find the CDF for $Y$ first, then differentiate to find the PDF.

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & = P(Y\le y) \\
& = P(Z^4 \le y) \\
& = P(|Z| \le y^{\frac{1}{4}}) \\
& = P(-y^{\frac{1}{4}} \le Z \le y^{\frac{1}{4}}) \\
& = P(Z \le y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ -\ P(Z\le -y^{\frac{1}{4}}) \\
& = \Phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ -\ \Phi(-y^{\frac{1}{4}}) \\
& = \Phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ -\ (1\ -\ \Phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})) \\
& = 2\Phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ -\ 1
\end{align}

Now that we've found the CDF of $Y$, we can find the PDF of $Y$ by differentiating the CDF and using the chain rule.

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) & = \frac{d}{dy}(2\Phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ -\ 1) \\
& = 2\frac{d}{dy}\Phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ -\ \frac{d}{dy}1 \\
& = 2\phi(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\times \frac{d}{dy}(y^{\frac{1}{4}})\ - 0\\
& = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^{1/2}}{2}}y^{-\frac{3}{4}}
\end{align}

Apparently the equation itself is correct, but I got it wrong because I forgot to specify that **it only holds when $y \gt 0$ and is $0$ elsewhere.**

I'm having trouble how this support came to be. I know that a Normal distribution's support is defined on $(-\infty,\ \infty)$, and I guess I was under the assumption that the same would hold for $\mathcal{N}^4$. Where did the support for $y$, $(0,\ \infty)$, come from?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $z\in\mathbb R\implies z^2\ge 0\implies (z^2)^2\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you! You may also post an answer if you'd like. :)